# NSString or NSCFString in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, nscfstring

I m taking a NSMutabledictionary object in NSString like this :

```
NSString *state=[d valueForKey:@"State"];
```

Now sometimes state may be null and sometimes filled with text.So Im comparing it.While comparing state becomes NSString sometimes and NSCFString othertimes..So unable to get the desired result..

```
if([state isEqualToString@""])
{
//do something 
}
else
{
//do something
}
```

So while comparing it is returning nil sometimes.So immediately jumping into the else block.

I need a standard way to compare if the state is empty whether it is a NSString or NSCFString ...

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're unable to get the result you want, I can assure you it's not because you get a `NSCFString` instead of a `NSString`.

In Objective-C, the framework is filled with cluster classes; that is, you see a class in the documentation, and in fact, it's just an *interface*. The framework has instead its own implementations of these classes. For instance, as you noted, the `NSString` class is often represented by the `NSCFString` class instead; and there are a few others, like `NSConstantString` and `NSPathStore2`, that are in fact subclasses of `NSString`, and that will behave just like you expect.

Your issue, from what I see...

> Now sometimes state may be null and sometimes filled with text.

... is that in Objective-C, it's legal to call a method on `nil`. (`Nil` is the Objective-C concept of `null` in other languages like C# and Java.) However, when you do, the return value is always zeroed; so if you string is `nil`, any equality comparison to it made with a method will return `NO`, even if you compare against `nil`. And even then, please note that an *empty string* is not the same thing as `nil`, since `nil` can be seen as the absence of anything. An empty string doesn't have characters, but hey, at least it's there. `nil` means there's nothing.

So instead of using a method to compare `state` to an empty string, you probably need to check that `state` is not `nil`, using simple pointer equality.

```
if(state == nil)
{
    //do something 
}
else
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: So what shall I do and how to compare?

Comment: @Sindhia, I was editing my answer when you commented, you should have your answer now.

Comment: as u have said if I compare it with if(state == nil) eventhough state doesnot contain any text,it is jumping to else block.and when i see the console for description of state it says...Printing description of state.Thats it.no null or nothing..What to do ?

Comment: @Sindhia, how do you print `state`? You didn't show that in your question.

Comment: I mean if I mouseover that state i can see .So rightclicking and printing decsription

Comment: beside I could recommend the `state.length > 0` as well (or `... == 0`), it can give a bit more information of the `state` than `state == nil`, if you need more information, of course.

Comment: It's true that `[state length] > 0` should work for all cases, since `[nil length]` will return zero, too. So I guess that would be the most concise way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
if([state isEqualToString:@""])
{
//do something 
}
else
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it to be worked eventhough the text is empty..Ad may i know what is this :isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]?

Comment: can you please NSLog For your state

Comment: Sometimes Im getting null and sometimes nothing NSLog is not getting printed when it is empty

Comment: and can you please NSLog(@"Your dictionary > %@",d)

Comment: businessName = "Ewert's IBM Typewriter Service";
        city = "";
        phone = "(559) 732-3215";
        state = "";
        street = "";
        zip = ""; is my one of dictionary in array

Comment: your code is fine..there is not any problem...now just tell me that are you getting value in "d" from array

Comment: Yes im getting value in "d" from array

Comment: ok just do one thing, get you dictionary as -> d = [yourAry objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: businessName = "Ewert's IBM Typewriter Service"; city = ""; phone = "(559) 732-3215"; state = ""; street = ""; zip = "";

Comment: i think now you are able to enter in IF condition

Comment: are just do NSLog in your if and else condition..then revert me back that which is calling

Comment: if([state isEqualToString:@""])
{
NSLog(@"If condition");
}
else
{
NSLog(@"else condition");
}

Answer (score -1):

You must have to type cast it to get the correct answer.

```
 NSString *state = (NSString *) [d valueForKey:@"State"];

  if(state != nil)
  {
      if(state.length > 0)
      {
           //string contains characters
      }
  }
```

Comment: No, you don't have to typecast. In C and Objective-C, a typecast from a pointer type to another pointer type only shuts up the compiler, it does nothing at runtime.

Comment: k if typecasted how to compare?if(state==nil)?or something elz?

Comment: No im not asking this.Actually state should compared whether it is NSString or NSCFString returning null or nil or empty .