# Convert NSCFString to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nscfstring

I am getting a dictionary from server

```
myDictionary = 
{
"rank":"1",
"color":"red",
"position":"middle"
}
```

Now I want to check the value of key "position" in if condition

I am doing it like this

```
if ([[myDictionary valueForKey:@"position"] isEqualToString:@"middle"]) {
        //do Some stuff
} else{
        //do some other stuff
}
```

but data type of `[myDictionary valueForKey:@"position"]` is `_NSCFString`, so it does not compare value properly and never goes in if loop even the value is correct.

how do I convert it into `NSString` so that I could compare it in if condition ?

I have seen these questions..

[NSString instance reports its class as NSCFString](https://stackoverflow.com/q/393873/2407907)

[Getting an NSString from an NSCFString](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6516293/2407907)

[NSString or NSCFString in xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13717310/2407907)

from these question I just came to know that
*`NSString` is really a container class for different types of string objects. Generally an NSString constructor does return an object that is actually of type `NSCFString`, which is a thin wrapper around the Core Foundation `CFString` `struct`.*

**but they didn't help me..and no one actually telling how to convert in into NSString, so please don't mark it as duplicate.**

Comment: Try this if ([(NSString *)[myDictionary valueForKey:@"position"] isEqualToString:@"middle"])

Comment: tried it already..doesn't help..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to convert `_NSCFString` to `NSString`. As a subclass of `NSString` it's guaranteed to respond to `-isEqualToString:` (and every other method in `NSString`). Your issue is not coming from the string, likely it is coming from `myDictionary`. Try logging all the keys in the dictionary and make sure it is behaving as expected.

Comment: I know its been so long, but, please post some more explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @VladislavKan Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393873/nsstring-instance-reports-its-class-as-nscfstring?lq=1) for a related question. `NSString` is the parent class from which all subclasses are derived.

Answer (score 0):

`CFString`s can be cast to `NSString`s as per the docs

> [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) is “toll-free bridged” with its Core Foundation counterpart, [CFStringRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFStringRef). See [“Toll-Free Bridging”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH2) for more information on toll-free bridging.

```
NSString *nsString = @"Hello";
CFStringRef cfString = (CFStringRef) nsString;
```

You really want to work out why the values aren't being equal. Separate out your method calls:

```
NSString *positionValue = myDictionary[@"position"];
NSLog(@"Position value: %@", positionValue);
if ([positionValue isEqualToString:@"middle"]) {
    // do Some stuff
} else{
    // do some other stuff
}
```

Comment: What does position value log out?